# Error while updating Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on VMware

Tags: vmware-workstation

I tried updating my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on VMware workstation 11 but I got the error shown in the picture below.

[image: error update]

My host machine is a Lenovo IdeaPad 300 with Windows 10 Pro, Intel Core i5, Intel® HD Graphics 510, 6 GB RAM and AMD Radeon Graphics.

Also, Ubuntu is not working smoothly although I gave it 2 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

About the error: looks like Ubuntu was already looking automatically for updates (and locking the packages database) so your manual check for updates failed to lock the packages database. Your option here is to wait some time (1 minute or so should be enough) and re-try the manual command.

About the Ubuntu performance: 2 GB of RAM should be ok for 32 bits but not ok for 64 bits. Also, Ubuntu's Unity requires 3D features from the graphic card - the emulated vmware graphic card might not provide the necessary speed for 3D stuff (and especially if no specific vmware video driver is used). Your best option here is to make sure the vmware video driver is installed & used - there's a vmware driver in the xserver-xorg-video-vmware package or you could install the vmware tools.

Comment: What ram size recommended for ubuntu 16.04 on vmware?

Comment: Ubuntu 32 bit - 2 GB RAM. Ubuntu 64 bit - 4 GB RAM.